# Sight reading by computer: can anyone suggest a usb-to-MIDI interface for Win 7 64-bit?

Tags: sight-reading, digital-piano

I'm planning to use some one of the flash-card style sight reading trainers on the net (asymptopia,etude,jalmus etc) but need to connect my laptop (Win 7, 64-bit) to my Yamaha P-70 (weighted keyboard), using its MIDI terminals.

I got a USB to MIDI adapter for  £5 and this didn't work. Can anyone advise one that plugs and plays with 64-bit Windows 7.

sight reading in the style of a computer game with automatic key feedback seems a much smarter and less painful way to wire you brain to read sheet music and make playing new music much more accessible.

Responses much appreciated

Comment: Unfortunately Dr. Mayhem is right, this is a question that would be better answered by looking at specs of various models. That said, I will also say that you will almost certainly not find anything in that price range that will work. If you spend closer to 20-40, your chances get much much higher. The M-audio Midisport series would likely be a good fit.

Comment: Many recent keyboards and digital pianos have USB MIDI interface and can be connected to a computer with USB cable without any adapter, but unfortunately Yamaha P-70 seems not among them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you might be better off looking at manufacturer's specs to identify adapters that will work with your OS. It isn't really a music question, which is what we limit ourselves to here.

That said, I have had good success with M-Audio kit. Some of their products give a range of audio and MIDI inputs and outputs. They are not in the £5 range though.

Comment: Thanks for this reply. This seems such an obvious requirement - surprised everyone isn't doing this. I'll take a look at M-Audio, thanks